# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" Error message in Javascript when calling a method in an object

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have a problem when calling a function from a button in HTML that gives me the: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error. I don't think there's anything wrong here.. Or there is something that I haven't taken into account. Thanks in advance for answering!

I have a lot of JS files, this is because this is a school assignment and we're now learning the Model, View, Controller (MVC) method.

I have this button:

```
<button onClick="ControllerBKE.reageerOpKlik()">Ok!</button>
```

I then have this Javascript code that creates an object of ^ "ControllerBKE":

```
"use strict"
window.onload = reageerOpStart();

function reageerOpStart()
{
    var controllerBKE = new ControllerBKE();
}
```

Here is the line of code that is in the "ControllerBKE" that should, but is not reacting to the button:

```
function ControllerBKE(){
    this.reageerOpKlik = reageerOpKlik;

    function reageerOpKlik(){
        alert('hoi');
    }
}
```

This is just a small portion of a big code. But I get the error message when I click on the button instead of getting an alert with 'hoi'.

Comment: Just as a side note, just for good practice, try avoiding inline javascript like the `OnClick=""` attribute and instead use the `element.addEventListener("click", function(){})`

Comment: @Lior This sound like an easier solution, how would I specify that line to a button if I have multiple buttons?

Comment: @user3775849 if you have multiple buttons set the onclick on the container (like document) then use event.target to figure out what was clicked and act accordingly: `document.onclick=funciton(e){ControllerBKE.reageerOpKlik(e);}` and in reageerOpKlik use `e.target` as that's the thing that was clicked unless you're using IE because they use window.event instead of passing the event as an argument. More info about constructor functions, prototype and the value of `this` can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @user3775849 You can listen to events on the container like HMR wrote which is better memory wise or if you are adding elements dynamically. If those aren't an issue (as this is a school assignment), you can take a more simple approach and use a distinctive selector for that button with an ID or a Class. Let's say you add an ID to that button `id="okBtn"` then you can query that element `var okBtn = document.querySelector("#okBtn");` and then use that in the event listener: `okBtn.addEventListener("click", YOUR_CALLBACK_FUNCTION)` where YOUR_CALLBACK_FUNCTION is your callback function :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" I have done exactly what you said. I have posted all of my codes to pastebin: [HTML](http://pastebin.com/WdEpiy3C), [CSS](http://pastebin.com/BSF7AmaF), [JS](http://pastebin.com/J1vrnnUZ).  The javascripts are all the affected once in one paste. I really hope I've made a dumb mistake and it's just easily fixable.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is referred to as a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). Your function has a limited scope. That is, it can only be called inside of `ControllerBKE()` where it is defined, not from outside the function.

What you have effectively done though is expose that closure via a property on your instance of `ControllerBKE`. While this works, it would fit more with the prototypal structure of JavaScript to add it to `ControllerBKE.prototype`.

It's important to remember that JavaScript is *Prototypal* not *Object Oriented*. While this may act similar to object oriented encapsulation, the two have different concepts and uses.

Look at the following example:

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="controllerBKE.reageerOpKlik()">Ok!</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
"use strict";
window.controllerBKE = new ControllerBKE();

function ControllerBKE () { }

ControllerBKE.prototype.reageerOpKlik = function () {
    alert('hoi');
}
```

I've simplified some of your code and refactored it to support the *prototype* object that JavaScript provides us with.

The first line is adding the controllerBKE variable to the window object. This gives it a global scope across the page, allowing your `onclick` function to have access to it.

The next line is a simple function wrapper. This will create an instance of `ControllerBKE` of type `object`.

The function you're trying to call is now attached to the prototype of `ControllerBKE`. This means that any instances of `ControllerBKE` created with the `new` keyword will have access to this function.

Check out the full functionality in the fiddle below:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/ngGa8/2/)

**References:**

[`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

[Object Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: @user3775849 Not a problem. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

`reageerOpKlik` is an instance method. You have to use it from an instance. The simplest solution (not the best) is to create a global controller instance. There are many ways you could get rid of that global variable, but it's beyond the scope of the question.

```
function reageerOpStart()
{
    window.controllerBKE = new ControllerBKE();
}


<button onClick="window.controllerBKE.reageerOpKlik()">Ok!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :D But this doesn't work for me.. :( Now I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reageerOpKlik' of undefined"

Comment: That must mean your code is not calling `reageerOpstart`. Did you debug it? Did you check if it's being called and the global is being set?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code

```
<button onClick="ControllerBKE.reageerOpKlik()">Ok!</button>
```

is trying to call `reageerOpKlik` on your prototype object `ControllerBKE`.

What you probably mean is

```
<button onClick="controllerBKE.reageerOpKlik()">Ok!</button>
```

where `controllerBKE` is an instance of your prototype.

However, you have another problem. The function:

```
function reageerOpStart()
{
    var controllerBKE = new ControllerBKE();
}
```

Creates `controllerBKE` in the scope of the `reageerOpStart` function, meaning that it's not avaiable in the global scope, which is where your button click handler would expect it.

You might want to consider:

```
 <button onClick="APP.controllerBKE.reageerOpKlik()">Ok!</button>

 APP = {}
 function reageerOpStart()
 {
     APP.controllerBKE = new ControllerBKE();
 }
```

Or, better still:

```
 <button id="myButton">Ok!</button>

 function reageerOpStart()
 {
     var controllerBKE = new ControllerBKE();
     document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            controllerBKE.reageerOpKlik();
     });
 }
```